# Repair espresso stained oak furniture

Tags: wooden-furniture, hardwood-refinishing, stain, wood-finishing

One of those kids glow in the dark bracelets leaked overnight onto our nightstand and it dissolved the finish. I sanded it down to what I thought was bare wood, but the new stain is not taking very well. Thoughts on how to repair?

[image]

Comment: Maybe try a wood conditioner first? Your stain may not be stirred completely and you are only getting pigment....number of things. Bad batch of stain?

Comment: Nah, I have used this stain on another project in the same time frame.  It is very odd.  It feels like the wood is so hard it won't absorb.